# Breaking down a string and using keybd to send characters

Tags: c++, winapi

I have searched the internet for a good system for emulating keypresses in C++.

I want to send a string to another program but as far as I can see the GenerateKey function can only send one at a time. I created code to break a string down and send each letter individually but sometimes the number of a specific letter in the alphabet is sent instead of the letter itself. (e.g. I enter "h" the computer spits out "8")

How can I fix this and is there a better way to do it? Thank you!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <winable.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<time.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void GenerateKey(int vk, BOOL bExtended) {

    KEYBDINPUT  kb = {0};
    INPUT       Input = {0};

    /* Generate a "key down" */
    if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
    kb.wVk  = vk;
    Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki  = kb;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

    /* Generate a "key up" */
    ZeroMemory(&kb, sizeof(KEYBDINPUT));
    ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    kb.dwFlags  =  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
    kb.wVk = vk;
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki = kb;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

    return;
}    

int main() {

 SetConsoleTitle( "sendkeys" );
string sentence;
while (1){
  cin>>sentence;
  char letter;
  int track = 0; 

  while(sentence[track] != '\0') {

    cout<<sentence[track];
    letter = sentence[track];     
    GenerateKey(letter, FALSE);
    track++;    
}    
}    
}
```

Comment: GenerateKey('a', FALSE); this generates key a,

Comment: Have added the `winapi` tag, as this really has nothing to do with C++ itself.

Comment: The reason that GenerateKey('h'...) gets you an 8 is because SendInput takes a VK value, which identifies a key on the keyboard, not an ASCII char. The VK and ASCII values do overlap for 0-9 and A-Z - uppercase; but any other ASCII values end up getting you a 'random' key. Lower case h has ascii code 0x68; look this up in winuser.h, which has all the VK_ values defined, and you'll see it's VK_NUMPAD8, so the system treats it as pressing 8 on the numeric keypad. This will get you either 8 or an up-arrow, depending on numlock. Sending 'H' will get you H vs h depending on state of caps lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of approach is really complicated (you have to manage state of SHIFT, CONTROL, and ALT, convert special characters to ALT+0xyz combos) and if the user changes keyboard focus in the process, keys can go to the wrong window.

Using `SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT)` or `SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL)` you could send a whole string at once to a particular window.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into that.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the synax to used to send a string?

Comment: Or is it a standalone function??

Comment: @Edmund: Those functions are part of the Win32 API, just like `SendInput`, and you can find their documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761633.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally familiar with some of the API you're using, but I'm going to assume you're trying to send text to the `stdin` of some other process?

If it's a child process (i.e. one your process launched itself), you can use pipes and redirected I/O as explained in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I am sorry to say that i am woefully unfamiliar with what you are talking about. I will look into it though.

Comment: `SendInput` sends keyboard events to the UI message loop, not `stdin`.

Comment: @Ben: gotcha. @Edmund: in that case, this method probably isn't what you need. Please feel free to ignore!